# org.web3j 4.5.18 ethGetBalance get stuck

Tags: web3j, java

I'm using the following simple code in order to obtain the wallet balance:

```
Credentials credentials = Credentials.create(privateKey);  
web3.ethGetBalance(credentials.getAddress(), DefaultBlockParameterName.LATEST).sendAsync().get().getBalance();
```

After retrieving the correct amount, the method simply get stuck, keeping running. Any idea?

Comment: How do you know that is got stuck? Any console logs?

Comment: From Netbeans, I notice that the process is running. After several attempts, I can confirm that it  is the istruction illustrated in this post to get stuck.

Comment: Thre problem is related to the issue 1085: https://github.com/web3j/web3j/issues/1085